# SVN check out alternative

Tags: svn

Previously i have check out the resource project using following SVN url (url is just e.g.):

[SVN URL #1]

```
http://example.com/repos/a2/Web/branches/grails/MyDemo-1.0.2
```

Now above resource check out SVN Url is changed to :
[SVN URL #2]

```
http://example.com/repos/a2/Web/branches/grails/MyDemo-1
```

I am using `"TortoiseSVN 1.7.12"`

Question:
Now while taking the update using URL `[SVN URL #1]` it shows the error like

```
"Error: Target path '/Web/branches/grails/MyDemo-1.0.2' does not exist"
```

So without doing fresh check out for `[SVN URL #2]` is there any alternative ?

Please,can anyone reply to this question ?
Thanks in advance !...

Comment: Read [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You must [`svn switch`](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/switch/) your Working Copy to the new URL (note **Note** on this page)